# Gravar JS no banco de dados com $_POST

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

Olá.

Tenho um script PHP que executa um INSERT em um tabela do meu banco de dados.

A array $_POST[txt_mensagem] mostrada no código deveria aceitar conteúdos JS, mas ela fica vazia após o submit. Ele deveria aceitar por exemplo um simples alert('ola')

Pesquisei no manual do PHP como aceitar uma cadeia de caracteres inseguras no POST mas não encontrei nada a respeito.

Agradeço antecipadamente a atenção de todos.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dados_conexao.php"); 

if ($_POST)
{
    echo 'valor: ' . $_POST['txt_mensagem'];
    try { // tenta fazer a conexão e executar o INSERT
        $conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario , $senha); //istancia a classe PDO
        $comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_mensagens (de, para, mensagem) VALUES ('$_POST[txt_de]', '$_POST[txt_para]', '$_POST[txt_mensagem]');";
        echo $comandoSQL;
        $grava = $conecta->prepare($comandoSQL); //testa o comando SQL
        $grava->execute(array());           
    } catch(PDOException $e) { // casso retorne erro
        echo('Deu erro: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
    }
}?>
```

Formulário

```html
<form method="POST" >
   <label for="de">Para: </label>
   <input type="text" name="de">
  
            <label for="para">Para: </label>
   <input type="text" name="para">

   <label for="mensagem">Mensagem: </label>
   <input type="text" name="mensagem">  

   <button type="submit"> Enviar </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Como é o formulário que envia os dados para esse código?

Comment: Editado, coloquei o HTML na pubicação! obg.

Comment: Faz assim e veja o que retorna: `echo 'valor: <textarea cols=100 rows=50>' . $_POST['txt_mensagem'].'</textarea>'; exit;`

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, para detectar se o formulário foi postado, use:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
```

O nome do seu campo no formulário é `mensagem` e não `txt_mensagem`, por isso a linha `echo 'valor: ' . $_POST['txt_mensagem'];` não funciona.

Na montagem da QUERY, além dos nomes errados, arrays em uma string devem ser incorporados entre parênteses, e também faltam as aspas nos nomes dos campos...

Substitua:

```
$comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_mensagens (de, para, mensagem) VALUES ('$_POST[txt_de]', '$_POST[txt_para]', '$_POST[txt_mensagem]');";
```

Por:

```
$comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_mensagens (de, para, mensagem) VALUES ('{$_POST['de']}', '{$_POST['para']}', '{$_POST['mensagem']}');";
```

Seu código PHP revisado:

```
<?php
session_start();
include("dados_conexao.php"); 

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
     $_POST['de'] = addslashes($_POST['de']);
     $_POST['para'] = addslashes($_POST['para']);
     $_POST['mensagem'] = addslashes($_POST['mensagem']);
    echo 'valor: ' . $_POST['mensagem'];
    try { // tenta fazer a conexão e executar o INSERT
        $conecta = new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor;dbname=$banco", $usuario , $senha); //istancia a classe PDO

        $comandoSQL = "INSERT INTO tb_mensagens (de, para, mensagem) VALUES ('{$_POST['de']}', '{$_POST['para']}', '{$_POST['mensagem']}');";

        echo $comandoSQL;

        $grava = $conecta->prepare($comandoSQL); //testa o comando SQL
        $grava->execute(array());           
    } catch(PDOException $e) { // casso retorne erro
        echo('Deu erro: ' . $e->getMessage()); 
    }
}
?>
```

Qualquer dúvida ou erro, referente a essa pergunta, só comentar aqui abaixo.

Comment: Deu certo a resposta acima?

Comment: Caro Allan, agradeço o seu tempo e dedicação em analisar e revisar meu código. Eu implementei da forma que propôs e a página realiza normalmente os INSERTs no banco, porém, o que eu necessito é que a página aceite comandos JS.

Se eu gravo o texto "Olá Mundo", tudo funciona bem, mas se tento gravar "<script> alert('Olá Mundo')</script>" a página não aceita esta cadeia de caracteres. Grato!

Comment: Tente usar com aspas duplas, pois as aspas simples já estão sendo utilizadas no conteúdo: <script> alert("Olá Mundo")</script>

Comment: Ou então pode tratar o POST antes com addslashes. Cria uma linha para cada post logo depois do primeiro IF, exemplo: $_POST['de'] = addslashes($_POST['de']);

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Testa e informa se está funcionando.